# Not able to start `django` project in local as well as in docker

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, docker

I am using `Docker` to deploy `Python2.7` application with `Django1.8`. 
I am facing some issue from last two days and I found error as below.

Docker Image: `python:2.7-slim-buster`

Error:

```
root@64f8c580dd0a:/code# python manage.py runserver
read completed!
read completed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imagekit/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imagekit/conf.py", line 1, in <module>
    from appconf import AppConf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/appconf/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import AppConf  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/appconf/base.py", line 107
    class AppConf(metaclass=AppConfMetaClass):
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`uwsgi` configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = /code/config/wsgi.py
callable = application

uid = nginx
gid = nginx

socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
chmod-socket = 664

master = true

cheaper = 5
processes = 15
vacuum = true
```

I have installed below dependencies:

```
Babel==2.8.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
boto==2.38.0
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.95
cffi==1.14.0
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
copyleaks==2.5.1
cryptography==2.8
dce-lti-py==0.7.4
Django==1.8
django-admin-honeypot==1.0.0
django-allauth==0.31.0
django-appconf==1.0.4
django-ckeditor==5.2.2
django-colorful==1.0.1
django-common-helpers==0.9.2
django-cors-headers==1.0.0
django-cron==0.5.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.6
django-environ==0.4.3
django-extensions==1.5.0
django-filter==1.1.0
django-hosts==2.0
django-imagekit==4.0.1
django-model-utils==2.0.3
django-mysql==2.2.0
django-phonenumber-field==1.3.0
django-polymorphic==0.6
django-recaptcha==1.3.0
django-redis==4.8.0
django-rest-framework-docs==0.1.7
django-rest-swagger==0.3.3
django-storages==1.1.8
django-uuslug==1.1.8
djangorestframework==3.1.0
docutils==0.16
drf-extensions==0.3.1
drf-nested-routers==0.11.1
enum34==1.1.6
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
future==0.18.2
futures==3.3.0
html5lib==1.0b8
httplib2==0.17.0
inflect==0.2.4
ipaddress==1.0.23
jdcal==1.4.1
jmespath==0.9.5
jsonpickle==0.9.0
lxml==3.7.3
MySQL-python==1.2.5
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
openpyxl==2.6.4
paypalrestsdk==1.13.1
paytm==0.1.8
phonenumberslite==8.12.1
pilkit==2.0
Pillow==3.2.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.20
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyOpenSSL==19.1.0
pyotp==2.2.6
pyPdf==1.13
PyPDF2==1.26.0
python-dateutil==2.4.0
python-openid==2.2.5
python-slugify==1.2.4
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==3.11
raven==6.1.0
redis==3.4.1
reportlab==3.3.0
requests==2.9.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.1.13
six==1.9.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
Unidecode==0.4.18
uWSGI==2.0.18
xhtml2pdf==0.0.6
xl2dict==0.1.5
xlrd==1.1.0
XlsxWriter==1.0.5
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Django==1.11.15 and python 2.7. Please, share the solution if you find it. I'll do the same!

Comment: it looks like you are running incompatible versions of python, django or another module

Comment: @Martin Below answer works for me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Django-appconf version 1.0.4 only supports Django 1.11 and up and Python 3.5 and up.
(https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf/blob/v1.0.4/setup.py). You need to downgrade to at least version 1.0.2 (supports Python 2.6+, doesn't say which django version: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf/blob/v1.0.2/setup.py)

Comment: I had this problem because I used `django_compressor==2.3`, which apparently includes `django-appconf==1.0.4`. I fixed it by explicitly adding `django-appconf==1.0.3` to my requirements.txt (also upgraded to `django_compressor==2.4`)

Comment: Same, wasted a couple hours on this. I was getting this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814582/upgrading-python-from-2-7-15-to-2-7-18-breaks-django-app-with-syntaxerror-noqa and it was because of `django-appconf` using v1.0.4. See https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf/issues/59 for further details.