# Upgrading python from 2.7.15 to 2.7.18 breaks Django app with SyntaxError (import AppConf # noqa)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm in the process of migrating an old python 2.7.15 app towards 2.7.18.

I created a new virtualenv and installed the same requirements.txt (there was no difference in dependencies), but the server fails to start with the following error:

`invalid syntax (base.py, line 107)`

[image]

My main issue is that I can't locate the origin of the problem. From the Stacktrace, it seems its an exception thrown from Django's internals, but I'm not sure.

Also, I don't explain why it'd break considering the dependencies are the same as before.

Would you have any idea of what's causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was due to `django-appconf` which was using `1.0.4` which isn't compatible with Python 2. Pinning `django-appconf==1.0.3` in my `requirements.txt` fixed the issue.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984631/2391795

See https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf/issues/59